# In MongoDB , should I use normalized or embed for following case?

Tags: mongodb, database-design, database, nosql

Its going to be a Web based Asychronus , multi-user chat.
I am not sure to embed everything in one table. Channel document and Embedded Messages as SubDoc.
Or Normalized, Two different Table , Channel and Messages like Relational Databases.

```
Channel: [
  {
    _id: ObjectId(…),
    title: ''
    descr: ''
    owner: ''
    mods : []
  }
]

Message: [
  {
    _id: ObjectId(…)
      msgid:''
      from : 'UserID'
      msg : ''
      Channel : "Channel'sObjectID"

  }
```

versus

```
Channel: [
  {
    _id: ObjectId(…),
    title: ''
    descr: ''
    owner: ''
    mods : ['UserID','UserID',]

    Message: [
      {
          msgid:''
          from : 'UserID'
          msg : ''

      }

  }
]
```

Messages are Chat Messages and will need to Write alot (as many insert due to multi-user requriement). So if i want to write i need to Query down to Channel's message and write there. Will it hit more performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get more and more messages per channel as time passes, you should put the individual messages as separate documents into another collection.

The reason is that MongoDB doesn't like documents which grow over time. For performance reasons, MongoDB keeps every document in a consecutive section of the physical files. When a document grows to exceed that section, it needs to be moved to another location in the file. This constant reallocation can be a real performance hook. Very large objects are also bad for caching. To further discourage growing objects, MongoDB imposes an artificial size limit of 16MB per document. A chat channel with 100 byte per minute average chat activity would exceed this limit in about 3 months.

Comment: Oh , 16MB Per document is including Embedded Doc? If embedded Document grows , it will also hit main document right? With multi user env it would easily outgrow within a few days. I was thought embedded docs are treated as seperated ones. Thanks alot!

Comment: @V3ss0n Yes, embedded documents are a part of the document they are embedded in.